# Selenium Webdriver C# How to test an element is not present?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This element can be found when a required field has been filled out:

```
IWebElement e1SK = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath(baseXPathSendKeys + "div[2]/textarea"));
```

When the required field is not filled in, the above element should not be present.

The test throws an exception:

**OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with**

Is this something I need to create a method for or is it even more simple than that?  If you could show an example, it would be helpful, I'm still fairly new to C# and Selenium Webdriver.

I have read that I might be able to user something called findwebelements then checking to make sure the result has a length of zero, but am not sure how to implement that either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a straightforward approach to the problem:

```
if (Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath(baseXPathSendKeys + "div[2]/textarea")).Count != 0)
{
    // exists
}
else
{
    // doesn't exist
}
```

You could create a method `Exists(By)` to test elements:

```
public bool Exists(By by)
{
    if (Driver.Instance.FindElements(by).Count != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call it when you want to test something:

```
By by = By.XPath(baseXPathSendKeys + "div[2]/textarea")
if (Exists(by))
{
    // success
}
```

Comment: are u sure these code blocks doesn't throw exceptions when the elements are missing/not visible.

Comment: @Anuragh27crony Absolutely.  `FindElement()` will throw an exception if no element is found, but `FindElements()` returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` of length 0 if no elements are found.

Comment: +1 but you can use LINQ to shorten it further, rather than explicitly checking `.Length != 0`, check for `.Any` which will return true/false depending if the `List` has *something* in it.

Comment: This looks great!  Does anyone know which reference I need to add to use .length?

Comment: @MattJoe Correction:  .Length should be .Count.  I forgot that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` has a `Count` property, not a `Length` property.

Comment: I have to add that the error can also be due to the fact that an element is in fact not visible.  The answer totally misses this very important point in my opinion.

Comment: Both the WebDriver and WebElement implement ISearchContext.  You can add an Exists extension method to ISearchContext to make it available to both the WebDriver and the WebElement.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below code snippet. If you are writing logic within the step definition method then the below code would be handy as method nesting is not advisable.

```
 Boolean elementnotpresent;  
       Try
                           {
                               IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Element XPath"));
                           }
                          catch (NoSuchElementException)
                            {
                              elementnotpresent=true;
                            }
                            if (elementnotpresent == true)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Element not present");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Element is present");
                            }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange case, when selenium was not throwing a NoSuchElementException exception, but MakeHttpRequest timed out.

So i had come up with idea, that i got the attribute innerHTML of parent HTML element, and assert that it doesnot contain not wanted element.

```
   Assert.IsTrue(!parent.GetAttribute("innerHTML").Contains("notWantedElement"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago but you can try something like this

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Timespan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElements(By.WhateverYourLocatorIs("")).Count == 0);
```